# Splunk Alert when no events/ zero count of events

Tags: alert, splunk

I have an alert in splunk that checks for different threshold (count of events) for every URL. The alert works perfectly with the logic below. BUT when there is no incoming events/traffic from incoming interfacing system (ie count = zero), then there is no alert triggered. Need help with the syntax. I tried different syntax for fillnull or append but I've not been able to get it working. Appreciate any help. Here's the Alert below.

```
index="abc" sourcetype=abc:Prod_logs (host="abc*") 
| bin span=15m _time
| stats count BY _time URL 
| stats avg(count) AS Avg_count_15m BY _time URL 
| eval eventHour=strftime(_time,"%H")
| fillnull value=0 Avg_count_15m
| fields _time URL Avg_count_15m eventHour 
| where (
(URL="/abc/summary" AND Avg_count_15m < 1000 AND 
eventHour>02 AND eventHour<=05) OR
(URL="/abc/summary" AND Avg_count_15m < 22000 AND 
eventHour>05 AND eventHour<=24) OR

(URL="/xyz/billing" AND Avg_count_15m < 50 AND 
eventHour>=02 AND eventHour<=05) OR
(URL="/xyz/billing" AND (Avg_count_15m < 110) AND 
eventHour>=05 AND eventHour<=24) 
)
```

Comment: Why would you want the Alert to trigger with both "some" results and "no" results?

Comment: Your `fillnull` is never going to populate anything - `stats` has already calculated that field (after your previous `stats` kept it (if it existed))

Comment: Actually, we receive requests from multiple sources, if some of the sources are down, then the incoming traffic goes down by x%. So, we check the count in 15 min interval. It works perfectly well when the count is 1 or more. But the web server was completely down and did not process any traffic ..... received zero but failed to detect that it's a zero

Answer (score 0):

*Most likely*, this is not a *search* problem, it's an *Alert config change* needed

Edit your Alert actions thusly:

1. [image: choose your Alert]
2. [image: edit the Alert]
3. [image: change Trigger Condition]
4. [image: choose a new rule]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `appendpipe` command to make up for missing events.  See this run-anywhere example.

````
| makeresults annotate=1
| eval URL="/abc/summary"
``` The above defines test data.  Delete IRL. ```
| bin span=15m _time
| stats count BY _time URL 
| stats avg(count) AS Avg_count_15m BY _time URL 
| eval eventHour=strftime(_time,"%H")
| fillnull value=0 Avg_count_15m
| fields _time URL Avg_count_15m eventHour 
``` Create fields where no matching events exist. ```
| appendpipe [ stats count(eval(URL="/abc/summary" AND eventHour>02 AND eventHour<=05)) as Count 
  | eval URL="/abc/summary",Avg_count_15m=0,eventHour=05 
  | where Count=0 | fields - Count ]
| appendpipe [ stats count(eval(URL="/abc/summary" AND eventHour>05 AND eventHour<=24)) as Count 
  | eval URL="/abc/summary",Avg_count_15m=0,eventHour=06 
  | where Count=0 | fields - Count ]
| appendpipe [ stats count(eval(URL="/xyz/billing" AND eventHour>02 AND eventHour<=05)) as Count 
  | eval URL="/xyz/billing",Avg_count_15m=0,eventHour=05 
  | where Count=0 | fields - Count ]
| appendpipe [ stats count(eval(URL="/xyz/billing" AND eventHour>05 AND eventHour<=24)) as Count 
  | eval URL="/xyz/billing",Avg_count_15m=0,eventHour=06 
  | where Count=0 | fields - Count ]
| where (
(URL="/abc/summary" AND Avg_count_15m < 1000 AND 
eventHour>02 AND eventHour<=05) OR
(URL="/abc/summary" AND Avg_count_15m < 22000 AND 
eventHour>05 AND eventHour<=24) OR

(URL="/xyz/billing" AND Avg_count_15m < 50 AND 
eventHour>=02 AND eventHour<=05) OR
(URL="/xyz/billing" AND (Avg_count_15m < 110) AND 
eventHour>=05 AND eventHour<=24) 
)
````